# Getting an error with angular-gauge version 5 and angular version 16

Tags: angular

I am trying to use angular-gauge version 5 with angular version 16. However, when I try to build the angular app, I get the following error:

```
Error: node_modules/angular-gauge/lib/gauge.component.d.ts:79:80 - error TS2344: Type '{ dialStartAngle: { alias: "dialStartAngle"; required: false; }; dialEndAngle: { alias: "dialEndAngle"; required: false; }; dialRadius: { alias: "dialRadius"; required: false; }; min: { alias: "min"; required: false; }; ... 10 more ...; animationDuration: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"dialStartAngle"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "dialStartAngle"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? David